# Интерактивные графики python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

Необходимо сделать на python интерактивный график: парабола через три точки, серединную точку должна быть возможность двигать мышкой, параллельно в режиме реального времени должен перестраиваться график (части от первой точки до второй и от второй до третьей). Кто-нибудь может подсказать, где посмотреть, куда копать? До этого использовал matplotlib и pyqtgraph, но не смог применить для этой задачи(может, невнимательно читал).

Comment: Вы можете показать то что вы использовали  с pyqtgraph и что вы там пробовали.

Comment: "где посмотреть, куда копать?" - если Вы использовали PyQt, то приблизительное направление такое: ставим обработчик на событие DragAndDrop, считываем координаты мышки в этот момент, пересчитываем их в X и Y на плоскости графика,  задаём новые координаты средней точки и перерисовываем график.